# Parsing Google Maps API for Latitude and Longitude

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the lat/lng of an address with the Google maps API. I am having trouble parsing the JSON result just to store the lat and lng values as PHP variables. Anyone able to help me parse this?

**This is what I have so far:**

```
<?php

$jsonObject = file_get_contents(
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true");

$object = json_decode($jsonObject);

$lat = $object->results[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lat;
$lng = $object->results[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lng;

echo "$lat, $lng";

?>
```

**This is the JSON feed (the lat/lng values are about two-thirds the way down the code):**

```
  {
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "1600",
           "short_name" : "1600",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
           "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Mountain View",
           "short_name" : "Mountain View",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Santa Clara",
           "short_name" : "Santa Clara",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "California",
           "short_name" : "CA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "94043",
           "short_name" : "94043",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 37.4216410,
           "lng" : -122.08550160
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 37.42298998029150,
              "lng" : -122.0841526197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 37.42029201970850,
              "lng" : -122.0868505802915
           }
        }
     },
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geometry` and `location` aren't arrays, try

```
$lat = $object->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $object->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Comment: Thanks Musa. You nailed it!